# Firestore triggers is just never call

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I am trying to listen to the changes in all the documents of my collection Profile.

I have look at the firestore documentation and I have try all the trigger (OnCreate, OnDelete, OnUpdate, OnWrite) but they just don't get call when I create or delete a document

I have no idea why this is not working, it seems fine to me

If you guys have an idea what is my problem, it will be very helpful !

Here is my code

I listen to the change like this :

```js
exports.listenToProfileChange = functions.firestore.document('Profile/{uid}')
    .onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
            console.log(snapshot, context);
        });
```

I create a profile like this :

```js
application.post("/profile/create", (req: any, res:any) => {
    const profileContent = req.body;
    firebase.firestore().collection('Profile').doc(profileContent.uid).set(profileContent).then(() => {
        res.status(201).send('Document is create with success')
    }).catch((error) => {
        res.status(404).send(error);
    })
})
```

Comment: Is the document getting created when you call your API endpoint? Do you have any other Cloud Functions and do they work? Are you on a Blaze plan (required for Cloud Functions)?

Comment: Hey thanks for the interrogation. So the document is getting create with success and I am on Blaze plan so this is not a problem. I only have 1 usages of cloud functions and it is to start the server like this functions.https.onRequest(application) and it is working fine. But I think I have a problem with my cloud functions because the function.config() always return {} even thought I try to add Algolia configuration